# Is there a tool for visualizing the geographic locations of research?

Tags: journals, tools, literature-search, publications

Many e-journals search tools contain much metadata in their database. For example, they have the "location" entry required for some citation formats, which at least shows the location of the journal, but the might also store the original authors' university name.

Is there any tool that can allow researchers to either (a) search a term and see a map of where the articles are coming from or (in some similar form or other) (b) see a world map showing where research in a particular area is geographically concentrated?

Comment: interesting question: could you try and rework it and explain why would you want to do so?

Comment: Here is an example use of this I am familiar with, [Health GeoJunction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apps.geovista.psu.edu%2Fhgj%2F&ei=uCugU-zANcaOqAa1u4GQBA&usg=AFQjCNF5AlORvZco35DH6dBqGGQpPMZsvQ&sig2=MwuXJZHAEJF-1Mg57eeq1A&bvm=bv.68911936,d.b2k). See *HEALTH GeoJunction: place-time-concept browsing of health publications* ([MachEachren et al., 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1476-072x-9-23)). The link to the interactive site appears just like a limited mock up though.

Comment: If the *location* entry is just the publisher location, it is probably rather misleading than enlightening, as it merely indicates where the company that produces the journal happens to be registered, or happens to have its headquarters. The journal itself might, but need not necessarily be composed and edited in that place, and the single articles published in the journal come from researchers all over the world and most probably not from precisely the publisher's location.

Comment: With that said, this other question and its comments might hint at some ways to retrieve such data: [Where can I search for researchers in a specific field by location?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42361/where-can-i-search-for-researchers-in-a-specific-field-by-location)

Comment: See http://journalmap.org

Comment: @mankoff: It is helpful to provide some context along with external links. In this case, the required context would be that JournalMap indicates locations associated with a limited number of journal articles (roughly 20,000) from about 1300 journals, seemingly mostly centered on zoology. The locations apparently do *not* indicate where the researchers or labs are based, or where the articles were written, but rather, where the objects of the studies were located (for instance, hundreds of articles about marine life are shown in the middle of the ocean).

Comment: Thomson Reuters' [Researcherid](http://www.researcherid.com/) includes some author-specific geographic search abilities. For instance, here's a [map of people citing me](http://labs.researcherid.com/mashlets/rid/mashletsServer.jsp?rid=G-9700-2012&mid=CitationDistribution&cat=Map).

Answer (score 2):

this is an active aera of research in Geography of Science. We've been working with sociologists of science and bibliometricians to assemble a geocoded database of scientific publications, based on the Web of Science database.

We've not (yet) produced a publicly available interactive search tool like the one you describe, but it's a possibility. Instead, we have published several papers and an interactive tool to geovisualize the collaborations between co-authors of papers : http://www.coscimo.net/ (in french)

If you're interested in this question, i can provide a bibliography.

- A conference paper :
  http://sticonference.org/Proceedings/vol1/Grossetti_Geographical_348.pdf
- A research paper :
  http://usj.sagepub.com/content/early/2013/11/20/0042098013506047.full.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen to this is for Elsevier journals most (all?) have a journal insights page which among other useful information such as impact factor and review speed has the geographic location (country) of primary authors of all their articles. For example here is the page for [Measurement](http://journalinsights.elsevier.com/journals/0263-2241). Its only on the country level and doesn't link author and location but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an interesting paper :

http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2793

Towards a Frontier of Spatial Scientometric Studies
by Song Gao

In this paper, the author cites several visualization tools :

http://linkeddata.org/

http://spatial.linkedscience.org/

http://semantic-web-journal.com/SWJPortal/

http://stko-work.geog.ucsb.edu:8080/map/

Answer (score 1):

For historical mathematicians: [MacTutor](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Map/) (St Andrews) has some map tools.

[image: map]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I am a little late, but if this is still an unanswered question, I have built a web application that will extract research locations from a corpus of research titles and abstracts.  For a corpus of 1,000 public health articles we achieved sensitivity of 71%, accuracy of 85%, and precision of 97%. Also, inferential analysis of the data identified similar results with the validation data set.  The paper is currently in review, but I am happy to share the program with anyone interested in it.