# Where can I search for researchers in a specific field by location

Tags: tools, literature-search

Where can I search for some authors of publications or researchers in a specific filed (e.g. Computer science) and in a specific country (USA, China, ...)

For example I would like to find all people who work on *Data Mining* located in *Iran*

Comment: There is no such central database, especially not one that covers *all* researchers in a given area.

Comment: While it's a rather vague mapping, one of the best bets I could imagine is using DBLP (or some queryable port of it, such as [Faceted DBLP](http://dblp.l3s.de/?q=&newQuery=yes&resTableName=query_resultKUFXRZ)), query for all publications in as many prolific venues of the field you're interested in, and then filter the linked authors based on their `foaf:homepage` attribute. This might at least provide you with a somewhat probable estimate of what institution (and thereby, which country) the researcher is (or was?) affiliated with. (Quite unreliable; but maybe just about better than nothing.)

Comment: I think your best bet is to find out what the major relevant institutions are, and then use their websites.  But that will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest that you use a variant of [snowball sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_sampling).  Start with the largest, most visible research university in that country (e.g. Iran).  Do a web search for the departments most likely associated with the topic (e.g. data mining). Look at the web pages associated with the most prominent researchers.  You will find listings of their published papers.  In those published papers, you will see co-authors, many from the same university and (importantly) from the same country.  Follow the trail of co-authors and repeat these procedures with their web pages.

In a similar fashion, find conference held in this geography.  It is likely that there will be a high concentration of local participants and conference committee members. They may or may not be important in the grand scheme, but you will find them.

Using this procedure, you should be able to enumerate 90%+ of the people involved in any one specialty in any one (small) geographic region.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to get a first set of names is to use one of the large bibliographic databases - [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/) or [Web of Science](http://apps.webofknowledge.com/) will let you search by affiliation/address. Once you have identified a suitable group of papers (eg by keyword/topic searching) you can filter it to only show papers where at least one author had an Iranian affiliation. You'll then be able to work through these pulling out the relevant authors.

Unfortunately, Google Scholar does *not* let you search by affiliation and so isn't much use here.

(Scopus, for example, has 9500 papers published since 2014 which match a title/keyword/abstract search for 'data mining', but only 146 of these have an Iranian author)

Comment: Please provide link to the mentioned sites, especially the web of science

Comment: Added. Note that both of these are commercial subscription-only services - you will need to be coming from an institution which has a subscription. Google Scholar is free, but doesn't have the affiliation data.